# Euler totient function - $|(Z/nZ)^*|=\phi(n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove that $|(Z/nZ)^*|=\phi(n)$

Can someone please direct me to that proof?

I couldn’t find it on the internet.

Thanks.

Comment: It's literally a direct corollary of Bezout's Lemma.

Comment: What is your definition of $\phi(n)$? Because for me the statement you wrote is true simply by definition.

Comment: @Mark I presume OP is using the common divisor definition.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n#Group_axioms

Comment: @Rushabh Mehta, then OP just needs to show that an element $a\in\mathbb{Z_n}$ is invertible if and only if $\gcd(a,n)=1$. Anyway, you already wrote it is a duplicate.

Comment: You lose serious style points for writing $\phi$ rather than $\varphi$ for the totient function!